# DNS setting of a domain

Tags: dns, hostname

I have a domain,

> `www.xyz.co.uk`

now I would like to point for example,

www.data.xyz.co.uk to the ip address of my server(digitalocean)

So far what I did is, I have created a hostname on dns managementconsole of godaddy, with `data.xyz.co.uk` and pointed that to my ip address.

I am little confused wether that is it or I need to do more on my server ? Secondly when I do `ping data.xzy.co.uk`  in terminal I get unknown host response.

Could somebody points me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the resolved the issue by adding A record in DNS settings of my hosts account and pointing that record to a desired Ip.